# Application error in heroku after successfully deployed - Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

> Error detail is:

```
**An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.**
```

> Here is logs details by command heroku logs --tail

```
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384637+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384637+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384644+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384644+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384651+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384652+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384654+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384661+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384663+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384664+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384671+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384672+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384679+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384679+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384687+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384687+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384689+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384696+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384696+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384703+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384703+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384711+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384711+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384718+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.384719+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2022-04-07T06:14:27.517957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-04-07T06:14:27.751744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: can you search your code for the `require_relative` statement, and then edit your question to add them in as code blocks?

Comment: sorry i can't understand what you say. New logs are following 2022-04-09T00:19:52.240179+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2022-04-09T00:19:52.389982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-04-09T00:19:52.814605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-04-09T00:19:54.125953+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=damp-coast-67678.herokuapp.com request_id=545279d6-e0eb-4c6f-b379-771b7860e0ba fwd="182.187.0.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Again, ignore the logs for now. They mention that you have a `require_relative` that's failing. Please search your code for that phrase